# jquery jScrollPane: Scroll content height exceeds item list size

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollPane plugin for my project. In my project there is a list of items that can be scrolled. Items will be loaded from xml later. Initially there are 2 items. The problem is that initially the scroll panel height exceeds the main content size & the scroll bar keeps moving down even if there is no more than 2 item. My code is bellow:

```
<script>
$('#scrollerContent').jScrollPane();
</script>

<body>
<div id="container" style="max-height:229; visibility:hidden">
<div id="scrollerContent" style="max-height:229">
<div id="1stContent">1stContent</div>
<div id="2ndContent">2ndContent</div>
<div id="3rdContent">3rdContent</div>
<div id="4thContent">4thContent</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

The item list is loaded from mouse click event:

```
<div id="listBar" onClick="loadItems()"></div>

loadItems(){

var divHeight=145;

if(itemLoaded){

if(3rdItemLoaded){

document.getElementByID("3rdContent").style.visibility= visible;
document.getElementByID("container").style.height= divHeight+ "px";
document.getElementByID("scrollerContent").style.height= divHeight+ "px";

}

if(4thItemLoaded){

document.getElementByID("4thContent").style.visibility= visible;
document.getElementByID("container").style.height= divHeight+ "px";
document.getElementByID("scrollerContent").style.height= divHeight+ "px";

}

}

else{ //By default 2 items loaded 

var divHeight= 145;
document.getElementByID("1stContent").style.visibility= visible;
document.getElementByID("2ndContent").style.visibility= visible;
document.getElementByID("container").style.height= divHeight+ "px";
document.getElementByID("scrollerContent").style.height= divHeight+ "px";

}

}
```

if the program reaches the last else condition that loads 2 items by default, then it causes the problem. The scroll-content height exceeds.Am I doing something wrong??